# Seperating same values into columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to take a list like this:

[image: original table]

and convert it to this, where the same values line up by column for each row record:

[image: end result]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to just populate the grid with a `SEARCH` formula.

[image: Spreadsheet view]

I have added column headers which are used in the formula to determine the matches.

`=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH(C$1,$B2)>0,C$1,""),"")`

Put this formula into cell `C3` and drag it over and down.

`SEARCH` will return the location, counting from the left, of the contents of `C$1` within the string in cell `$B2`.  `SEARCH` is not case-sensitive, so if you want `a` to be not equivalent to `A`, then use `FIND` instead.

Both `SEARCH` and `FIND` will return errors if not found, so the `IFERROR` captures that and returns `""` instead.